# Ошибки в микроразметке - logo.height и url

Tags: schema.org

Есть такой html код:

```html
<div class="content" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
            <link itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemscope href="site.ru" />
            
            <div itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
                <div itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
                    <meta itemprop="url" src="https://site/logo.png"/>
                    <meta itemprop="width" content="400">
                    <meta itemprop="height" content="80">
                </div>
                <meta itemprop="telephone" content="+1111111111">
                <meta itemprop="address" content="Беларусь">
                <meta itemprop="name" content="site.ru">
            </div>
</div>
```

В проверке гугл валидаторм получаю ошибки:

`Атрибут logo.height имеет недопустимое значение.`

`Необходимо указать значение для поля url.`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить эти ошибки?

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/82027/correct-image-dimensions-when-using-schema-orgs-logo-image

Answer (score 0):

Вот так должно быть:

```
<div class="content" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
                <link itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemscope href="site.ru" />

                <div itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
                    <div itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
                        <img itemprop="image url" src="https://site/logo.png" alt="">
                        <meta itemprop="width" content="400px">
                        <meta itemprop="height" content="80px">
                    </div>
                    <meta itemprop="telephone" content="+1111111111">
                    <meta itemprop="address" content="Беларусь">
                    <meta itemprop="name" content="site.ru">
                </div>
    </div>
```